# Android - Push notifications when entering geofence area

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have developed an android application with geofences.

When a user enter the radius of a geofence the user gets a notification. The problem with this is, that only the user entering the geofence gets the notification.What I want to do is: When a child enter the radius of the geofence (the school) the parents gets a notification.

Any ideas on how I can do this?
The application is backed by Firebase where I have two types of users (children and Parents). I have looked in to using Firebase Cloud Functions. Is that a good idea?

Comment: You can achieve this simply using Realtime Database and watch changes in a specific node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain a bit further? I am still a bit confused

Comment: Couldn't i just create a node in Realtime Database when the child enters the school and use Firebase Cloud Functions to send a notification?